# Pause button is stopping AVAudioPlayer rather than pausing

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

`UIToolbar` has `UIBarButtonItems` play, pause and stop buttons. The play and stop buttons are working fine but the pause button is stopping the audio player rather than pausing audioplayer. It should pause the audio file and resume the audio file.

Looking at my code below, do you see anything missing?

```
- (void) playaudio: (id) sender
{
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Theme" 
                                                     ofType:@"mp3"];   
   NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];   

   self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                    initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

   self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
   [self.audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)pause: (id)sender
{   
    [audioPlayer pause];  
}

- (void) stop: (id) sender
{
   [audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: Please give a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to acheive, with more code ;)

Comment: Maybe try using your property instead of the ivar directly? `[self.audioPlayer pause]`

Comment: have tried that too earlier. But it didn't worked.

Comment: How are you currently updating your objects on screen? That could help us help you help us all.

Comment: i just added piece of code please have a look

Comment: Are you sure? Do you want the whole program to pause ?

Comment: Yes that's what the logic of the app is.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you linked the unpause action to playAudio, this piece of code is there:

```
self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
```

Which will restart the audio file from the beginning, not from where it is paused.

If this isn't the problem, you should definitely post more code.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm following what your trying to do your problem is that you're implicitly starting timers to fire off the view display methods and expecting them to stop without any messages or logic. If so, you're not trying to sleep the app,just stop those methods from firing.

A simple solution with the existing code would be to set a BOOL appIsPaused and In your playpauseAction method set the bool appropriately depending on the state of the button.

Then in your displayviewsAction wrap your code in an if statement ( ie. if(!appIsPaused){. }).   If the app gets paused before the view update methods are fired the BOOL will be set to YES and the view won't get updated.

Comment: Assuming you have the BOOL appIsPaused declared, in your playpauseAction: method after the line `[audioPlayer pause] ` add `appIsPaused = YES;` and after `[audioPlayer play]` add `appIsPaused = NO;`.  Then, start displayviewsAction method with `if (!appIsPaused){FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init]; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void) stop: (id) sender
{
   if (audioPlayer.playing)
    {
        [player stop];
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    }
}
```